# Cannot link my table view controller on storyboard to my code

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, ios8, xcode6gm

I am writing an app in XCode6. Currently I have "SelectionTableViewController.h" and "SelectionTableViewController.m" such that you could add/remove checkmarks on select. Also, I have a table view controller segue in the storyboard, that is triggered by a static cell in the previous table view controller. I set up the trigger in storyboard so I did not write the code for "prepare for segue" or anything.
I want the cell to be checked by default, so I have done the following:

- Changed the view controller to "SelectionTableViewController"
- Set the identifier of prototype cell on my storyboard to "SelectionCell"
- Changed the cell's background color to orange and accessory to checkmark

Below is my SelectionTableViewController.m:

```
@implementation SelectionTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
           forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SelectionCell"];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Select";
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [[[MyStore sharedStore] allCategories] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSString *category = [[[MyStore sharedStore] allCategories] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[[MyStore sharedStore] allNamesForCategory: category] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SelectionCell"forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *category = [[[MyStore sharedStore] allCategories] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *items = [[MyStore sharedStore] allNamesForCategory: category];

    cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[MyStore sharedStore] allCategories] objectAtIndex:section];
}

@end
```

My program runs on the simulator, and the items listed in the cells are correct. However the cells does not have the default checkmark on the cell before I do a selection. Nor are the cells orange. I know I can set up the default checkmark and the background color in code easily, but I just want to figure out how to do this in the interface builder, as I would be dealing with the UI a lot when the program is set up.

Hope someone can help me on that as I'm kinda new to iOS programming and this is the first time I have ever used Storyboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out myself! I deleted the code that registered "Selection Cell". Then I did some minor changes to the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    Static NSString *selectionCell = @"SelectionCell"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:selectionCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Omit...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your implementation is `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will only be triggered by user's interaction only, therefore the initial selection doesn't show. You will need to make `tableView` aware of the selection state during initialisation too, else de-selection will not function as expected.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var selectedItem: Int = 5

    func updateSelection(selected: Bool, forCell cell: UITableViewCell) {
        cell.accessoryType = selected ? .Checkmark : .None
        // update other cell appearances here..
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // Note: happens after the initial tableView.reloadData()
        // Let tableView know who's selected before we appear, so that tableView is aware of the selection state.
        // Doing so will enable tableView to know which cell to deselect after a new selection.
        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: selectedItem, inSection: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .Middle)
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Item \(indexPath.item)"
        // Setup the selection appearance during cell creation
        updateSelection(indexPath.item == selectedItem, forCell: cell)
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // Keep track of the selection, and update cell appearance
        selectedItem = indexPath.item
        updateSelection(true, forCell: tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // As above
        updateSelection(false, forCell: tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!)
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually I have figured it out myself. Thanks!